# Print array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an <strike>JSON</strike> Array that is of the following structure:

```
[
    [
        ["ABC", [
            [0, 0.139], 0.14]],
        ["DEF", [
            [0, 0.02, 0.06, 0.015], 0.115]],
        ["GHI", [
            [0, 0.0722, 0.9], 0.105]]
    ]
]
```

I'm stuck at the part to print it in the format

```
ABC
    First:0, 0.139   Final: 0.14

DEF
    First:0,0.02,0.06,0.015    Final: 0.115
```

This shouldn't be too hard but I'm just not able to crack it and this is what I've tried:

```
$.each(data, function(i){
    var vc = data[0][i];
    var cw = data[0][i].[i][1]
    var arr = [vc, cw];
    vcat.push(arr);
});
```

and

```
for(i=0; i<len;i++){
    vc.push(data[0][i]);
    for(j=0;j<len;j++){
        cw.push(data[0][i].data[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods failed and I'm not able to figure the correct algorithm to print this tree.

Comment: Could you show us what you actually want the output to look like? I don't see any `Something, Something Else` in your input data.

Comment: I'm so sorry.. i've edited the question

Comment: Thank you. And is it safe to assume that those are arrays and not plain objects? Could you show the actual JSON with the brackets (you can prettify it on jspretty.com if you need to.

Comment: You should consider using proper objects instead of arrays for things that are not list-like. (`{"name":…, "values":{"all":[…], "last":…}}`)

Comment: This is an ajax response.. so I don't have control over the dataType being sent from the backend. @JLRishe, I've edited it again.

Comment: Does this help (using lodash): `_.zipObject`and then for each own object `_.flatten`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do:

```
var o = {};

$.each(data[0][0], function () {
    o[this[0]] = {
        First: this[1][0].join(", "),
        Final: this[1][1]
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qf25azhp/

Answer (score 0):

For once, you're iterating over `data`, so you need to use `data[i]` - you were always accessing `data[0]` only (and then some other properties).

Second, the string concatenation operator in JavaScript is the `+` (plus), not the `.`.

So your codes should rather look like this:

```
data = data[0];
$.each(data, function(i){
    var vc = data[i][0];
    var cw = data[i][1][0][0]+" "+data[i][1][1];
    var arr = [vc, cw];
    vcat.push(arr);
});
```

and

```
data = data[0];
for(var i=0; i<len;i++){
    vc.push(data[i][0]);
}
for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
    cw.push(data[j][1][0][0]+" "+.data[j][1][1])
}
```

(ignoring the possibly many other problems)